# Python: how to group rows by one column and pick one row by another column?

Tags: python, csv, merge

I have a CSV file like this:

```
student | score
John    |  A
John    |  C
Mary    |  B
Mary    |  D
Kim     |  B
Kim     |  A
```

Each student has multiple scores, and I want to merge score information under unique student with the highest score.

I want to have a table like this in result:

```
student | score
John    | A
Mary    | B
Kim     | A
```

I tried to find a post about this but failed. Is there any approach to do this using built-in library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dictionary, and store only the highest value found so far. Because the scores are given as letters, that means you need to find the 'lowest' letter, lexographically:

```
import csv

students = {}

with open(inputcsvfile, 'rb') as scoressource:
    reader = csv.reader(scoressource)
    for name, score in reader:
        if score < students.get(name, 'Z'):
            students[name] = score

with open(outputcsvfile, 'wb') as scoresdest:
    writer = csv.writer(scoresdest)
    for name, score in students.iteritems():
        writer.writerow([name, score])
```

Answer (score 2):

Group by student name using [itertools.groupby](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).

```
import csv
import itertools
import operator

with open('1.csv') as f, open('2.csv', 'w') as fout:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter='|')
    writer = csv.DictWriter(fout, fieldnames=reader.fieldnames, delimiter='|')
    writer.writeheader()
    for student, group in itertools.groupby(reader, key=operator.itemgetter('student')):
        max_score = min(map(operator.itemgetter('score'), group))
        writer.writerow({'student': student, 'score': max_score})
```

Comment: Great answer. Couldn't have been any more Pythonic IMO.